# Does reCAPTCHA work in html without domain name?

Tags: html, css, localhost, recaptcha

I'm developing a website using html and I want to make a human verification.I'm running the system locally.

In the reCAPTCHA website it is said that the plugin will only work at the given domain (and subdomains).

My question is: Is there any way to use the reCAPTCHA plugin on a localhost and i have tried using localhost and 127.0.0.1?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owj5k.png)

Answer (score 0):

yes register it with your localhost so you can use it 
[image]

Comment: there is no register button. if i clicked on submit button and copy my client site key to my  html web site it shows ERROR for site owner:
Invalid domain for site key